# Why do I have to print my canvas twice with html2canvas to get the right height?

Tags: javascript, canvas, crop, html2canvas

We're developing an AngularJS application in which I want to convert a div to an image using html2canvas. The issue is that it seems to crop the image at a height of about 1000 pixels. That is, unless I do it twice.

Let me explain.

So at first, I run this code to produce the image:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
var options = {
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
    width: 700,
    height: 700
};
html2canvas(div, options).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

It appends the canvas to the page and what I see is this:

[image]

Then I try setting `height: 8200` (the actual height of the document). I refresh the page and try again. This time I get this:

[image]

The height is greater than it was before but nowhere near 8200. It seems that no matter how much greater I set the height, it doesn't grow beyond this. It's almost as though it insists on printing images on 8.5 x 11 paper.

That is, unless I try printing the document twice in a row (i.e. without refreshing the page). Then I get this:

[image]

The whole document shows in the second column (it's too big to all fit in one screen shot, but trust me, when I scroll to the bottom, it's all there).

So my question is: why does it work the second time around? And how can I avoid having to print it twice to get the full image?